# Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to push ghcr.io/: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden

Tags: docker, github, gitlab, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am using GitHub Actions, for building and pushing a simple docker image to GitHub Container registry. My repository is inside an organization and I have configured secrets on organization level.

The job succeeds in logging in to ghcr, but when it tries to push it to ghcr it end with the following error:

> Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to push ghcr.io/: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden.

**github-actions.yml**

```
name: Build and Push Freeradius proxy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GCR_TOKEN}}
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@79abd3f86f79a9d68a23c75a09a9a85889262adf
      - name: Login to GHCR
        uses: docker/login-action@28218f9b04b4f3f62068d7b6ce6ca5b26e35336c
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ secrets.REPO_OWNER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GCR_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build and Push Docker Image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ac9327eae2b366085ac7f6a2d02df8aa8ead720a
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ghcr.io/${{ github.repository }}:${{ github.sha }}
```

I tried using different versions of `docker/setup-buildx-action` but it didn't worked!

Comment: Your workflow looks okay. Have you verified your PAT has the right permissions for this? This looks like a incorrect permissions issue. See https://github.com/docker/login-action#github-container-registry.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your repository action is not setting in `read and write permissions`
[image]